# how to insert into multiple tables in adf?

Tags: java, oracle-adf

i have Table1 with 5 columns and corresponding viewObject1

```
ID   Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 Value5
```

and there was ADF Form where all those values would inserted manually with inputTexts

but there is a complex enhance need to be done in this form which is :

if selected RemoteSource Insted of manual mode (which was already Done) then :
the 5 values will be retrieved from Another Table2 based on my selection of six Cascaded af:selectOneChoice , once selected , the InputText Will Populated with the 5 Values , which will be inserted in Table1 + 
and insert the 5 IDS which was selected from the 5 selectOneChoice to another table Table3 which has foriegn key of Table1
So I can retrieve it later if i open the edit Screen

what is the general steps i need to follow to Fulfill this requirements ?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle ADF when you need to update rows in 2 Database Table you have to do as follow :

- Create Entity Object based on table A
- Create Entity Object based on table B
- Create View Object based on Both Entity Object (To do so, will generate a View Object with a join between the two table. With the correct where/subqueries for your use case)
- Add the View Object containing both Entity Object to the Application Module
- Use this View Object from your datasource to create your form

When you'll commit this View Object both Entity Object will be commited and the two database tables updated. Same goes for inserts.

Comment: But there will be foreign key in table 2 for the newly created row in table 1 ? How i will make that If its one  view object ?

Comment: A view object doesn't need to be the exact match of your database table. Just make your View Object the SQL query you need on your two entity object and that's it.

Comment: Thanks MrAdibou 
I've Done The Following :
1- Created EntitnyObject1 For Table1 (master)
2- Created EntityObject2 For Table2 (Detail )
3- Created Association Between them 1 to * (EO1 to EO2) (with composite checkbox selected ) 
4- Created ViewObject Based on the EO1 and EO2 
and Selected the Join to LEFT OUTER JOIN between them 
5- created viewLink and the source and destination is is the same Assoc
now when i try the createInsert Operation on this view Object I got the following Exception :

Comment: oracle.jbo.InvalidOwnerException: JBO-25030: Detail entity EntitnyObject1 with row key oracle.jbo.Key[-42 ] cannot find or invalidate its owning entity.
Any help ?