# Insert into 2 separate tables which are linked by primary key-foreign key

Tags: oracle-adf

Say I have 2 Table, Employee and Address with primary keys EmployeeID and AddressID respectively.
both tables are linked by the Address ID field and have one to one relationship.

Now in UI when I want to add a new Employee I want a single form where user can enter both the details from employee and address.

Both table have got the primary keys set as dbsequence in the EO and VO layer. There is a sequence and trigger implemented in the DB Layer. 
The address should be inserted first and the addressID generated should reflect on the row inserted on the employee table.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56795181/how-to-insert-into-multiple-tables-in-adf/56801970#56801970. Also when you create two EO based on table with foreign key, Jdeveloper automatically add a Link Association object.

Comment: I have not implemented any relations in the database layer. I have made the association in EO level.
I've made the VO based on the two entities both updatable. My Creation form won't display fields from the second table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid setting values on the Database level since it causes the below error

> another users changed the row  with primary key...

Try to initialize the AddressId Column value on entity level (Address Entity Object) using the below expression

```
(new oracle.jbo.server.SequenceImpl("ADDRESS_ID_SEQ_NAME",adf.object.getDBTransaction())).getSequenceNumber()
```

Then you can create a ViewLink with 1 to 1 relation between Address And Employee So the AddressId Will be defaulted with same value for both Address And Employee

Comment: If the tables have a foreign key dependency he doesnt need to add a View Link, ADF will automatically create a Link Association between the two Entity Object